# Identify This Plant (Flower)

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

I just bought this plant from flower shop, after it flowered it was very beautiful red flower, can anyone tell me what is this flower?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a *Gerbera*, which belongs to the daisy family (*Asteraceae*). Compare:

[image]

There are various species.

> The domesticated cultivars are mostly a result of a cross between *Gerbera jamesonii* and another South African species *Gerbera viridifolia*.[5] The cross is known as *Gerbera hybrida*. Thousands of cultivars exist.

(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerbera))